# (javaScript) value in and out of 'for loop'

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, console

I am a beginner with javaSCript and just wondering why the results are different when it's called "inside" the loop and "outside" the loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
console.log(i);
// prints 0 1 2 3 4 
}

console.log(i);
// prints 0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how var in JS works and also that's how for loops in all languages work.

When you declare a variable using var keyword it is hoisted to the function scope, or global if not inside a function. This lets you access var outside of the for loop scope. Try changing var to let and see what happens.

Secondly, you don't see 5 printed in the for-loop because of your condition `i < 5`. `i++` causes 'i' to go from 4 to 5 which breaks the for-loop conditions and the 'i' is not printed.

Lastly console.log(i) outside the for-loop should just print 5 because that is the value of i at that point and not

```
console.log(i);
// prints 0 1 2 3 4 5
// should print 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the for looping steps is :

- 1 - **define a variable**,
- 2 - **check the condition**,
- 3 - **run the code inside the loop**,
- 4 - **and increase the loop variable value by 1** ,

**But!** After defining the variable and After the first loop, it will ignore the first argument **var i = 0** and it will increment the loop variable by 1, and check the condition, why? Because in the for looping, the last thing  to do is increase the loop variable by 1,

So the last loop will increase the loop variable by 1 and check the condition ,

**Simply: the variable has changed through the loop to 5 because after the first loop it will increase the variable by 1 and checking the condition**

I hope my answer will be useful to you!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop it logs the numbers from `0` to `4`. The last `i++` sets `i` to `5`, and the loop stops because `i < 5` is no longer true. Then the `console.log(i)` after the loop logs this value.

Answer (score 0):

During the loop execution, the condition i < 5 fails for "5<5" but still the value of i here becomes '5' which is executed outside of the loop

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
console.log("inside loop: " + i);
// prints 0 1 2 3 4 
}

console.log("outside loop: " + i);
// prints just 5
```